# From AppEngine Objectify to Google Search Index - OutOfMemory

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search, objectify, google-search-api

I have around 1200 entities in my datastore. I want to add them to a Google Search index.. It was no problem when I had around 800, but now I run into a Java Out Of Memory error when trying to add them to the search index. Eventually I expect to have 100,000 - 500,000 entities that need to go into the index.. So I need to do this in the proper way..

I refactored my code to pull from the datastore using objectify only 50 entities at a time, add those to the index, and then pull another 50. This is all done in a for loop, 50 at a time, up until 1200.. But I still am getting out of memory errors.

Is there a better way?

```
    int entitiesPerFetch = 50;
    for(int i=0;i<numTotalEntities;i=i+entitiesPerFetch){
       List<MyEntity> ents = ofy().load().type(MyEntity.class).filter("year >", 200).order("-year").offset(i).limit(entitiesPerFetch).list();
       for(int g=0;g<ents.size();g++){
        try {               
            MyEntity myent = ents.get(g);
            String docID = myent.getID();
            Document doc = Document.newBuilder()
                            .setId(docID) // Setting the document identifer is optional. If omitted, the search service will create an identifier.
                            .addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("title").setText(myent.getTitle()))
                            .build();           
            index.put(doc);                             
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            continue;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I was pointed to Objectify.clear() to clear the local session cache. I will try that tomorrow and answer this question if that solves it, which I suspect it will.

Answer (score 0):

Calling Objectify().clear() after loading a lot of results has fixed the memory issue.

Comment: You should accept your answer. Doesn't matter who wrote the answer if it will help the next person. If you do that, will you put where in your code you ended up calling `clear()` please?